# Excel number format to hide FALSE

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for a way to hide all FALSE values in a column of booleans. I've looked at custom number formats, but I don't know how to target boolean values. Any ideas?

Comment: if your booleans are calculated, then wrapping it with an `IF` formula is an option.

Comment: You can use Conditional formatting to format the data to hide in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest, easiest way, and the one that leaves you the greatest formatting leeway, is to alter whatever formula you are using to wrap that portion in an `IF` that outputs "whatever" if the test is "TRUE" and "" if the test is "FALSE"... so if you have something as simple as `=A2=B2` you make it `=IF(A2=B2,TRUE,"")` and it's all handled. If the formula is hugely complicated, you still just wrap it in an `IF`. If you can easily locate where the "FALSE" comes from into the formula, you might prefer to just wrap that portion. The details are infinite, but the result is the same:  if the result would be `FALSE` and the display therefore would be "FALSE", then it will now result in `""` and display as nothing. If it feeds into further formulas that require the literal `FALSE` from it rather than "", then they would need adjusting as well, on their input end.

But it does leave your formatting, normal OR conditional, alone for whatever other purposes you might have for such, or just to keep a complication out of your hair. People read formulas and understand them as a matter of course when looking into fixing problems or updating/bettering a spreadsheet. They OFTEN will not think about a conditional format lying in the bushes. Not until after a lot of work/frustration anyway.

But if one would prefer to use formatting:

One might think that `FALSE`, as a Boolean and seemingly considered by Excel as a "0" ought to be something one can hide using the 3rd parameter in a standard number formatting string. However, it is actually the "0" that is considered a FALSE by Excel, not the other way around, and hence the way one has to coerce FALSE into being a "0" in many formulas.

In fact, it is considered Text by Excel for this purpose, though as a `Type` it has its own classification, one that is not "broken out" by Excel in setting up number formatting.

So if you blank the 4th parameter in a standard custom number formatting string (standard = "positive;negative;zero;text"), then `FALSE` will be blanked out. But... so will `TRUE` and presumably you don't want that.

But you can take advantage of the other main kind of normal custom number formatting string, the one that lets you have two conditions with their own formatting followed by a third format for anything not covered by the first two parts. So `[=0]"";0.00;0` will do the trick.

But there's strangeness in that, a couple strangenesses. First, the minor one:  Notice the condition, `[=0]` rather than `[=FALSE]`. Enter the latter and Excel changes it to the former. So for this purpose, Excel does the coercing of "FALSE" to "0" for its own reasons. Minor because Excel will change it for you and because you don't care so long as you needn't coerce the "FALSE" results to 0's.

The bigger one though: Rather fascinatingly, if there is no condition given in the second part, Excel seems to regard it as applying to everything... **IF** you enter a third part. If you do not, so perhaps use `[=0]"";-0.00`, then "-5" will appear as "--5.00" rather than "-5.00" and all numbers will get the same leading "-" so "5" shows as "-5.00" and so on. If you add a third parameter, `[=0]"";0.00;0`, say, then the interpretation seems to again regard the second parameter as not a condition (one could think of the preceding as Excel seeing the second parameter as a condition, just a completely inclusive condition), but rather as the formatting for negative numbers as the "-5" will now be "-5.00" suggesting such, but not locking it down, but "5" will display as "5" not "-5" or "-5.00" or "5.00" and changing the third part to `[=0]"";0.00;0.00` will see a "5" displaying as "5.00". So include the third part and the second becomes a normal negative number format with the third parameter the positive one. No fourth parameter will be accepted. Text displays as text. Strangely, `[=0]"";-0.00;@` returns you to the "--5.00" world so that's clearly not the precise explanation, deeper details must exist, but it's closer than help sites give.

So you can use `[=0]"";0.00;0` and accomplish your goal.

Comment: Oh wow, nice. I was looking for the number formatting solution but wasn't sure how to do it. I'm actually writing to excel through Python via ExcelWriter, so I was trying to avoid using if statements / converting to strings.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use Conditional Formatting -> New Rule ...** :

- For **Rule Type** select "Format only cells that contain"
- For **Cell value** select "equal to" and enter FALSE in the next text box

  [image: Screen shot]
- Sets **Format -> Font Color** to be equal to the background (such as white)

**Example of cells formatted with the above** (A1 to A6):

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).